# help remembering book title - multiverses/bladerunner-ish future. "sphere of influence. 2150"?

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to remember title (and author) of best sci-fi book i have ever read (at least thats what my fading memory tells me).

Plot revolves around multiple-universe theories - set on earth, 'hero' is given a brain implant that allows him to decide which future he wants to exist in (eg: coin toss produces 2 universes - one where it is heads, one tails) - he can 'choose' which of the 2 possible futures to take. The unchosen future is destroyed or disappears somehow(?).

Hero is tasked with finding a young girl who has same ability but can do it without implant. Plan is to find and kill her because the effect of her decisions (and now his) are affecting whole universe and aliens have wrapped solar system in some kind of event horizon to cut us off from universe until we sort out the problem.

Cant remember any real specifics; - lots of action (tech, guns etc), bladerunner-ish. Read it around 1990-5.

Googling hasnt got me anywhere but title potentially something like "sphere of influence. 2150"

If i can find this book, i will be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Greg Egan's book [*Quarantine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_(Greg_Egan_novel)).

[image: Quarantine novel cover]

Comment: Thats it! Thanks Daniel - ive been searching for this book on and off for last 10 years. 5 minutes on stack and bingo! awesome

Comment: No problem. To be honest it was obvious as soon as you mentioned the multiple-universe thing: that's pretty much Egan's speciality.